# Detect if a chair is occupied using Arduino with some sensors

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-ide

I want to detect if a seat is occupied by a person. This is [the answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/detect-and-stream-if-a-chair-is-occupied) that I found on Stackoverflow.

However, how accurate is the output of 4 suggested sensors? Will the computing of all these 4 sensor values into one boolean recognize a case when, for instance, a box of 40kg is placed on a seat and some person is just slightly "shaking" that seat with a hand? In those cases Arduino should recognize that a seat is not occupied by a person. Will it work with only 4 sensors or is there any better and more accurate solution (maybe some existing library)? I guess that CapSense-Library is not applicable in my case.

Comment: Then you can make a camera-based shape recognition. BUT then with a blow-up doll you can fake it. Ok, then let's compute also the weight. BUT then with a corpse you can fake it. Ok, then let's use a thermocamera to detect the temperature too. BUT you can use a fresh corpse, so you can still fake it. Of course these are absurd examples, but you have to understand that EVERY system can be fooled. Now, in my opinion the case of the "40kg box moved bya hand" is so marginal that it is not worth wasting time and money to find a way to detect it. I think that a single load cell is more than enough...

Comment: If you want to avoid the "static loads", then the easiest solution is to add a temperature sensor, I think. But... Again, in my opinion it's not worth even te time to think about solving this case ;)